# How are `remote functions` and `remote actors` made to run in a distributed manner under the hood in the ray library?

Tags: ray

I am interested in understanding how `remote functions` and `remote actors` are made to run in a distributed manner under the hood in the [ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) library. I have traced the code beginning from `ray.remote` to the following lines thus far:

- For functions:
  https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/6233cef22cc3c62034b4a40923d1eaebdfef883f/python/ray/worker.py#L1710
- For class:
  https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/6233cef22cc3c62034b4a40923d1eaebdfef883f/python/ray/worker.py#L1732

Beyond the above point, could you provide simple intuitive step-by-step explanation of how a `function` and a `class` is converted and ran in a distributed manner?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Please checkout the whitepaper for more internal details; https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lAy0Owi-vPz2jEqBSaHNQcy2IBSDEHyXNOQZlGuj93c/preview